# Changing pivot table data source

Tags: excel, vba

Nothing has made me more frustrated with VBA than pivot tables. I would like to simply specify a data source for a pivot table using  VBA.

```
Dim pvtcache As PivotCache
Dim Range1 As Range

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache _
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business Process Identification").Range("A1:Bc1693").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) _
, Version:=6)
```

I'm trying to open a workbook from a SP site, and then reference data for the data source, refresh, then close the workbook.

I get a runtime error '-2147024809' that says: 
"the PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. IF you are changing the name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field"

If I manually change the data source to the range specified in the code, there is no problems, only when I run this macro.

Note: The reference data for right now is in the same workbook, and I'm getting this same error. 
Note: I do not have hidden columns or rows, I have all my column headers labelled correctly, which is the usual cause of this problem

Comment: Issel do you want to change the sourcedata because it grows on your sheet, or it comes from a totally different source?

Comment: Once I figure out what the issue is, I plan on defining a range, and using that as the source data, it will change monthly, and there will be multiple Pivot Tables. I'm using a static reference for the moment to simplify and troubleshoot. Source data will come from a different workbook, saved on a SP site.

Comment: Using a `ListObject` as a data source, you never need to quadruple-check you're capturing all the rows ever again.

Comment: @Issel you can use a simple named range on your workbook referencing the other workbook like this: `=OFFSET(SHEETNAME!A1,0,0,COUNTA(SHEETNAME!A:A),COUNTA(SHEETNAME!1:1))` this will give you a dynamic range growing with the sheet, thought you will need to open the other workbook to refresh it but...

Comment: Mathieu Guindon, if I could up-vote that post 42 times, I would do it.  ListObjects (or Tables) are among the most under-utilized features of Excel.  So many times I've seen people doing so much work to maintain ranges that could be done with almost no effort by using a ListObject. When you include the ability to extend formulas automatically throughout the whole of the table, the vastly simpler syntax you see when creating formulas and the ease of adding/deleting rows, ListObjects become one of the best data management tools in Excel.

Comment: Thank you guys for advice on a dynamic range, but that isn't the issue. I will change this a lot once I get the error code figured out. The VBA code is giving me the error, as though I don't have a column header specified, or the column headers have changed when that is not the case.

Comment: If you reference by `Range.Address` - how should Excel differentiate between two workbooks? Again: This sounds like an `ActiveWorkbook`vs. `ThisWorkbook` problem...

Comment: -asger Right now, I have the data in the same workbook to simplify things. I'll modify this to reference a separate workbook after I get this error changed. I tested the code by specifying the workbook and worksheet in both places, and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

after trying MANY different approaches and variations, I found that if you turn the range you want into a table, and use "ListObjects" changing the source data on a pivot table will work:

```
Workbooks("SubLOBs").Worksheets("APQCL2").PivotTables("PivotTable4").ChangePivotCache _
Workbooks("SubLOBs").PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business Process Identification").ListObjects("Table1"))
```

I have no idea why. I have no idea why a parameter called "SourceData" can't simply refer to a range, but has to be in a table and referred to as a listobject. Pivot Tables can suck a dick.